# How do I get the controller and action from which a button was clicked?

Tags: grails

I am working on a project in which there is a "Add person" button that appears on multiple pages which redirects to a controller/view that lets the user fill out the required fields and add a new person to the database. However, I am stumped on how to make it redirect to the view that called it once the new person has been added. If possible, I would like to retain any user input that existed on the calling view when the add person button was clicked. Here is the code that adds the person.

I would need something like this at the end of my code.

```
redirect(controller: 'callingController', action: 'callingAction')
```

any help?

Comment: You haven't included the code that adds the person.

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for the edit. I was trying to figure out how to get code to appear in blocks like that but couldnt quite get it, so I didnt add all the code because it would have looked terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a form for that

```
<g:form url="[resource:person, action:'addPerson']" method="GET" >



<label for="personName">
   <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:field name="personName" value="" required=""/>
    <!-- put here your fields details like above-->

<fieldset class="buttons">
   <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="addPerson" value="Add Person" />
</fieldset>
</g:form>
```

You don't need to redirect methods to be called ...

Comment: Could you tell me a little more about what this entails? Is the form just something I could make a seperate file for? Or would I need to include it in every page that needs the add person button? Im very new to all of this so please forgive my lack of knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: nope. you can put it on main template which is on /views/layout/main.gsp (to be appeared on every pages)

for specific pages (not all) .. you can make _form.gsp and then render partial it on the page that you need to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [render](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Controllers/render.html).  Something like:

```
render(template: "myView", model: [person: newPerson])
```

You could also [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) to another controller if that's what you want.